# Auth0 API - create user - phone_number madness

Tags: auth0

It’s not easy to understand this API … phone number field …

The [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/post_users) says it's optional

*phone_number string (optional)
The user’s phone number (following the E.164 recommendation), only valid for users from SMS connections.*

my tries:

#1 request

```
{
  "email": "adriana.will@yahoo.com",
  "phone_number": "",
  ...
  "connection": "Username-Password-Authentication",
  ...
}
```

Response

```
Payload validation error: 'String does not match pattern ^\\+[0-9]{1,15}$: ' on property phone_number (The user's phone number (following the E.164 recommendation), only valid for users from SMS connections).
```

#2 request (without phone_number)

```
{
  "email": "adriana.will@yahoo.com",
"connection": "Username-Password-Authentication",
...
}
```

Response

```
Payload validation error: 'Expected type string but found type null' on property phone_number (The user's phone number (following the E.164 recommendation), only valid for users from SMS connections)
```

#3 request

```
{
  "email": "adriana.will@yahoo.com",
  "phone_number": "+113407178302",
  ...
  "connection": "Username-Password-Authentication",
...
}
```

Response

```
phone_number is not allowed
```

Anyone please ? What should I put ?

Comment: Which Auth0 API endpoint are you sending this payload with? A link to the docs you're reading would be helpful!

Comment: Added link to API documentation. 
I am using Auth0 Management API, they provide you one for your account ... mine is:
https://<my-user>.eu.auth0.com

Comment: Dealing with the same thing, is anyone able to resolve this yet?

Answer (score -1):

this does the magic

```
{
  "email":"test@test.com",
  "connection":"Username-Password-Authentication",
  "password":"password"
}
```